# Ruby Gem ConflictError

Tags: ruby

I receive this error:

```
Gem::ConflictError: Unable to activate standalone_migrations-4.0.5, because rake-12.3.0 conflicts with rake (~> 10.0)
```

How I can fix this version conflict?

```
error stack:
rake aborted!
Gem::ConflictError: Unable to activate standalone_migrations-4.0.5, because rake-12.3.0 conflicts with rake (~> 10.0)
/Users/Desktop/Genesis/gw_plugin/Rakefile:12:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What you did to get this error? What is the project you're working on? Rails/no-rails?

Comment: First I'd try deleting `Gemfile.lock` and doing `bundle install` just to be sure.

Comment: Deleting `Gemfile.lock` is a bad idea. Show us both `Gemfile` & `Gemfile.lock` first.

Comment: Why is deleting Gemfile.lock a bad idea?

Comment: @Kris that would upgrade all gems that are not locked in the Gemfile. You generally want to do that with caution since blind upgrades to Gems may break other things.

Comment: Gemfile.lock would get recreated anyway if you do `bundle update`. If Gemfile uses `~>4.0` providing the gem authors use semver it should be fine, i.e. no breaking changes.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is caused by some gem requiring an older version of rake. If I'm not entirely mistaken, try running `gem update`. In my case, that has solved some issues.

Comment: In case you're using bundler, yes. If you use the internal rubygems, you should be fine without it.